# Query mongo document to return all rows in a field

Tags: mongodb

For example, if I have a `name` field in mongo document `person`. In SQL, the query would be like `select name from person;` to return all names.
What is the equivalent in mongo?

I was thinking `db.person.find(<<What do I fill here>>, {name: 1});`

I was trying to retrieve all names while using mongo console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty JSON object `{}` matches all documents.

```
db.person.find({}, {name: 1});
```

Answer (score 1):

For correct syntaxe use best practices of mongoDB.

```
db.person.find(
   { },
   { name: 1, lastname: 1, _id: 0 }
)
```

In this exemple it shows only "name" and "lastname".